# about deploying polygon smart contract mumbai

Tags: hardhat, polygon

When I run `npx hardhat compile` I got this error;

```
Error: Cannot find module '@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\User\Documents\co\polygon-smart-contract-tutorial\hardhat.config.js
- C:\Users\User\Documents\co\polygon-smart-contract-tutorial\node_modules\hardhat\internal\core\config\config-loading.js
- C:\Users\User\Documents\co\polygon-smart-contract-tutorial\node_modules\hardhat\internal\cli\cli.js    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\User\Documents\co\polygon-smart-contract-tutorial\hardhat.config.js:1:1)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    'C:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\co\\polygon-smart-contract-tutorial\\hardhat.config.js',
PS C:\Users\User\Documents\co\polygon-smart-contract-tutorial> npx hardhat compile
An unexpected error occurred:

Error: Cannot find module '@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\User\Documents\co\polygon-smart-contract-tutorial\hardhat.config.js
- C:\Users\User\Documents\co\polygon-smart-contract-tutorial\node_modules\hardhat\internal\core\config\config-loading.js
- C:\Users\User\Documents\co\polygon-smart-contract-tutorial\node_modules\hardhat\internal\cli\cli.js    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\User\Documents\co\polygon-smart-contract-tutorial\hardhat.config.js:1:1)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    'C:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\co\\polygon-smart-contract-tutorial\\hardhat.config.js',
PS C:\Users\User\Documents\co\polygon-smart-contract-tutorial> npx hardhat compile
An unexpected error occurred:

Error: Cannot find module '@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\User\Documents\co\polygon-smart-contract-tutorial\hardhat.config.js
- C:\Users\User\Documents\co\polygon-smart-contract-tutorial\node_modules\hardhat\internal\core\config\config-loading.js
- C:\Users\User\Documents\co\polygon-smart-contract-tutorial\node_modules\hardhat\internal\cli\cli.js    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\User\Documents\co\polygon-smart-contract-tutorial\hardhat.config.js:1:1)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    'C:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\co\\polygon-smart-contract-tutorial\\hardhat.config.js',
    'C:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\co\\polygon-smart-contract-tutorial\\node_modules\\hardhat\\internal\\core\\config\\config-loading.js',
    'C:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\co\\polygon-smart-contract-tutorial\\node_modules\\hardhat\\internal\\cli\\cli.js'
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're probably missing all the dependencies. Try running `npm i @nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle @nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers chai ethereum waffle ethers hardhat` and try again.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is from [Patrck Collins's solidity course](https://youtu.be/gyMwXuJrbJQ?t=30636).

We need to delete the unwanted config file.

1. Find it

```bash
  npx hardhat --verbose
```

```bash
  hardhat:core:config Loading Hardhat config from /Users/hardhat.config.js
```

2. Then Remove it

```bash
rm /Users/hardhat.config.js
```

Try `yarn hardhat` again, it worked for me.